# Combobox transfer text to textbox eventhough typed or choose from drop down

Tags: c#, winforms

can i know how to get the current text in combobox into textbox in c#. This  means that, if the user type the text in combobox or select from drop down it should appear in the textbox immediately

```
   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: yup i checked both selectedindexchanged and textxhanged event

Comment: leave event also was not working

Comment: k i will show it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subscribing to the wrong event. What you've got is only going to run when `textBox1`'s text changes, not when `comboBox1`'s selection changes.

Subscribe to `comboBox1.TextChanged` instead, and use that same line of code.

Or just remove what you've got and copy this into the constructor of your Form, which does the same thing but is slightly more succinct (IMO).

```
comboBox1.TextChanged += (s,e) => textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to solve the task. You can use bindings.

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", comboBox1, "Text");
```